# ORA-12154 cannot connect to the database from sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus

ORA-12154 cannot connect to the database from sqlplus

tnsnames.ora

```
89# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: M:\app\oracleuser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DOCASSIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = DOCASSIST)
    )
  )
```

listener.ora

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: M:\app\oracleuser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = M:\app\oracleuser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:M:\app\oracleuser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )


DOCASSISTLISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

sqlnet.ora

```
# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

I am able to connect to the databse using tnsping

```
C:\Users\Manish>tnsping docassist

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 01-FEB-2
014 22:09:31

Copyright (c) 1997, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
M:\app\oracleuser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = DOCASSIST)))
OK (0 msec)
```

I tried creating a TNS_ADMIN environment variable as mention in this link here - [TNSPING OK but sqlplus gives ORA-12154?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966848/tnsping-ok-but-sqlplus-gives-ora-12154)
but I am still getting the same error when I try to connect to using sqlplus

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Sat Feb 1 22:08:57 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: SYSTEM@DOCTORASSIST
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Comment: You should try with `docassist` not `DOCTORASSIST` isn't it? Connect using `SYSTEM@docassist as sysadmin`

Comment: Enter user-name: SYSTEM@docassist
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor

Comment: You did `tnsping` as `docassist` and why you are trying to connect as `SYSTEM@DOCTORASSIST`? And make sure your listener is up and running

Comment: See this, might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d

Comment: i'm pretty new to this. I cannot access the Db from sqlplus .. or the sqldeveloper .. not sure how i can run this query. select value from v$parameter where name='service_names'

Comment: See the link I have posted, that will be helpful.

Comment: Please answer this, I would like to know how did you try to connect to your database? Have you tried as `SYSTEM@DOCASSIST as sysadmin`?

Comment: yes but i am getting invalid option error. so I tried as sysdba, then i was getting  ORA-12514

Comment: Then do as `SYSTEM@DOCASSIST`, no need to `as sysdba`

Comment: that gives me ORA-12514 again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(NONE)

Comment: try it where ? I cannot connect to the DB neither from sqlplus nor sql developer

Comment: Although this question is very old: The file SQLNET.ORA can be found in the TNS_ADMIN path (search registry for it). If this is not set default path is %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin.