# sqlplus gets ORA-12504 when using EZCONNECT syntax

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tns

Having the opposite problem as this person.
[TNSPING OK but sqlplus gives ORA-12154?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966848/tnsping-ok-but-sqlplus-gives-ora-12154)

I'm trying to install Oracle on a VM in VMWare Workstation.
I've tried to install Oracle 11g and 12c on:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Windows Server 2016 Tech Preview 3 (out of desperation)

In every case, I get the dialog that says "minimum requirements not met".
When I check the install log in AppData I get this.

> Checking whether the IP address of the localhost could be
>   determined... SEVERE: CVU do not support target environment

I've tried setting my VMs to use NAT as well as using a Bridged connection.
According to this thread, the 'CVU error' can be ignored. https://community.oracle.com/thread/2478769

Oracle installs successfully every time and it auto inserts an entry in my tnsnames.ora file. I can connect as the `sys` user by doing `sys@TNS_ENTRY as sysdba`

But the second I try using EZCONNECT syntax, it doesn't work. For example:

```
>sqlplus /nolog
>connect sys@localhost:1521/service
```

I then get an ORA-12504: TNS:Listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA. This is weird because I'm not even trying to use an entry from the tnsnames.ora file to connect. I've tried promoting EZCONNECT in the sqlnet.ora config manager in Net Manager.

I have verified that the Oracle installer did put the listener on my machine called "LISTENER"

I have another server running Windows Server 2012 R2 running on bare metal. I cross checked all of the tns, listener, and sqlnet configuration and their all identical (default configs that were created by the 11g installer)

I know VMWare supports Oracle databases on their VMs. I tried to stick to these best practices listed here. http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/partners/oracle/Oracle_Databases_on_VMware_-_Best_Practices_Guide.pdf

I checked `lsnrctl` to make sure that it's loading the configuration correctly.
I see my endpoint there when I restart the listener

`(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=mymachinename)(PORT=1521)))`

The firewall is off.

Here's the result of the tnsping:

> C:\Users\Administrator>tnsping localhost
>
> TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
>   on 17-SEP-2015 11:36:02
>
> Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Used parameter files:
>   C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
>
> Used EZCONNECT adapter to resolve the alias Attempting to contact
>   (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
>   OK (0 msec)

^looks exactly the same as the tnsping from my 2012 R2 bare metal server with 11g on it that works.

Am I missing something really easy here? I'm about at my wits' end with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a problem with the EZCONNECT syntax, not the databse configuration, as described [here](http://oradim.blogspot.com/2009/07/sqlplus-ezconnect-password-prompt-and.html) by Mark Williams.  The forward slash in the connect string is confusing EZCONNECT, it must be escaped like this:

```
C:\>sqlplus sys@\"localhost:1521/orcl12\" as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri Sep 18 13:10:19 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel like a complete idiot... I couldn't even connect from sqldeveloper which is strange. But things are working well now. :)

Comment: Permanent link for Mark Williams' blog in case it ever goes down. http://web.archive.org/web/20120717020405/http://oradim.blogspot.com/2009/07/sqlplus-ezconnect-password-prompt-and.html

Comment: Note that you must also use \"username\" in case your Oracle user name is not all uppercase too. Especially if you have both a _foo_ and _FOO_ user. W/o the \" around the user name, Oracle does its implicit uppercase transformation, and that's not the same user as intended perhaps! Yes, such non-uppercase user names are not recommended, and even more _overloaded_ by case only, but Oracle does allow and support it, so better be prepared.