# SQL loader shows error ORA-12546 TNS:permission denied when I try to run it against a remote database

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, tns

I'm trying to run sql loader with the following syntax on a remote bbdd:

```
sqlldr user/password@host.sid control=loader_control_file.ctl
```

(where host.sid is the remote bbdd tnsnames entry) and it gives the following error

```
SQL*Loader-704: Internal error: ulconnect: OCIServerAttach [0]
ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied
```

I have the connection configured in my local tnsnames.ora, tnsping resolves the sid and sqlplus connects (and works) correctly so apparently tnsnames setup is good.

I've also tried EZconnect syntax

```
sqlldr user/password@//host:1521/sid control=loader_control_file.ctl
```

buts gives the same error

I have no idea of what is wrong here. Any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966848/tnsping-ok-but-sqlplus-gives-ora-12154?rq=1

Comment: Your connection sting is jacked up somewhere.   What happens when you pass hard coded values in the connection string?  Try direct connect instead of variables.  The error will reveal itself.

Comment: maybe just try chmod 777 on the import file.  giving everyone access might resolve.

Comment: I've tried against a database on another remote server and everything went ok, so I think it should be a misconfiguration on the remote server. The sysop granted me ssh access to the server, so I could load it locally (and it worked). I still don't know where the problem is, but at least  I could workaround the issue, Thanks for the help!